# Input issues on react native gifted chat

Tags: react-native

I'm facing a problem with the android version.

Each time i send a message the input seems to be cleared but when i start typing again the previous value is merged to the new value.

Ex : if i want to send 2 messages "Hello" and "World"

first i send "Hello" then when i start to write "World" my input display "HelloW" so the value of the last send is merged to the new value.

This happend only on android. i've tried to manually manage by affecting the value of onInputTextChanged to text props and then clear it at each send but it doesn't fix it.

Any suggestion ?

Edit :

```
class Chat extends React.Component {
  state = {
    messages: [],
    text:"",
    clear:false
  }



  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      messages: [
        {
          _id: 1,
          text: 'Hello',
          createdAt: new Date(),
          user: {
            _id: 2,
            name: 'React Native',
            avatar: 'https://images.com/',
          },
        },
      ],
    })
  }

  onSend(messages = []) {
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, messages),
    }))


  }

  setCustomText = (text) => {


      this.setState({text:text})
  }





  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}} >
         <GiftedChat

            messages={this.state.messages}
            onSend={messages => this.onSend(messages)}
            bottomOffset={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 290 : 0}
            text={this.state.text}
            onInputTextChanged={(text) => this.setCustomText(text)}
            user={{
              _id: 1,
            }}
          />
          <KeyboardSpacer/>

      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: proved your code for find your bug

Comment: @Man Done. I thought there wasn't any bug in my code since the chat works perfectly with the ios version.

Comment: your code is perfect

Comment: for the first time i'm not happy to hear that. It will be though to find the problem.

Comment: where u find GiftedChat component

Comment: i am thinking that library not full working in android

Answer (score 0):

There is a react-native module to solve that https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-text-input-reset and make sure to import `findNodeHandle` from `react-native`